# How can I get exact delay between audio and video with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, sync

I know how to set a delay with ffmpeg's `-itsoffset` flag, but I want to know how to get and set exact delay time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is an intrinsic delay between the video and audio stream, there's no easy way to find out. Assume you're creating an audiovisual file where the audio stream was purposely offset using `itsoffset`. This will result in the audio presentation timestamps being changed, relative to the video.

Say, this is the original, assuming three audio frames per video frame (which is too few in practice):

```
V1       V2          V3    ...
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 ...
```

The audio frames will have the timestamps A1 = 0, A2 = 1, A3 = 2, etc.

Now you delay the audio stream:

```
V1       V2          V3    ...
xx xx xx A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 ...
```

Here, the first three empty samples will have the timestamps 0, 1, and 2, and A1 will have 3. For the player this means that V2 and A1 belong together, and there's nothing wrong with that.

If you want to estimate an initial offset, you'd have to inspect the audio stream manually, or use [`silencedetect`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#silencedetect) to detect the period between the start of the stream and the first audio sample that contains information, but this only works if the audio stream starts directly with a signal. If it's a fade-in of some kind, or starts at -∞ dBFS, you're out of luck.